# Programatically show data tip on plot

Tags: matlab, plot, tooltip

How to show **data tip message** on a matlab plot programmatically with only a mouse click, and without using `Data Cursor`, to show custom messages in different positions like the following:

[image: Data Cursor]

Comment: What do you mean "without using Data Cursor"? Those are data cursors. And what do you mean "programmatically with a mouse click"?

Answer (score 0):

"You can't." From the "Tips" section of the [help page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datacursormode.html) for the function `datacursormode`:

> You place data tips only by clicking data objects on graphs. You cannot place them programmatically (by executing code to position a data cursor).

But people do achieve this with hacking, like [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/controlling-plot-data-tips). The short version of what they are doing is

```
h = ezplot('sin(x)')
cursorMode = datacursormode(gcf);
hDatatip = cursorMode.createDatatip(h);
```